# How to perform child component validation without infinite loop in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have really simple example in react. Parent component pass data to the child component throug `props`. Inside child component i can change this data, also new data can be passed to the child component from the parent at any time. Also on the parent i have save button. After pressing it i should show validation message if some validations did not pass. 
I have implemented it in such a way. From parent i pass callback to notify parent that validity of the data has changed. Inside child i perform validation in three places:

- `componentDidMount` - to validate initial data
- `componentWillReceiveProps` - to validate data that can be passed from the parent
- `onChange` to validate entered data
  Any time child perform validation of data i call callback to inform parent about validity. The problem is in `componentWillReceiveProps`. With setState in parent this part causes infinite loop - see picture below.
  [image]
  Please check [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t5tdqefx/3/) Here in console you can see that i restricted infinite loop to 10 iterations to prevent you browser from crash.

As you can see there is infinite loop - because React call `componentWillReceiveProps` in not too smart way - every render cycle instead of callind it only when props actually changed.
I am really would like to know what is the react way to solve this issue. Should i store child state only in child ? I also tried to store child validity in parent out of state - but my coworkers said that this is not react way - why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I see your challenge:

- you want to have your validation method in your child component, because it is specific to this type of child (e.g. a password input field). - but in react, no outside component (except grandchildren) are allowed to directly call this method.
- you want your parent to know about the validaty of each of the children components (e.g. to determine of all the fields validate and a form submit is allowed) - so you need the result of the validation method in the parent component, and this must be state

Your co-workers are correct: react does not like you storing component-wide variables outside of state. Because such variables are completely independent from react lifecycle methods etc. and would get you in debugging hell quickly.

I would advise you to make following changes to prevent the endless loop:

- do NOT store the validity of the child in the child state. Save the result + any message in the parent, and pass it as a props to the child. Child only renders the props.
- implement `shouldComponentUpdate()`, which checks if any of the props or state variables have changed. If not return `false`, otherwise, return `true`.
- move your call to `validate()` from `componentWillReceiveProps` to `componentWillUpdate()`. This ìs called after `shouldComponentUpdate()`. So only if props or child state have changed, will validation (and re-render) take place.

Comment: Thank you this is what i was looking for.

Comment: One additional note. In child component there will be two places where validaion is performed componentWillUpdate and componentDidMount - for initial validation as componentWillUpdate  is not invoked during initial rendering. Final jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/t5tdqefx/4/

Comment: Yeah, you can leave the validation in componentDidMount. This is only fired once, so no chance of endless loop. + no need to check if props really changed, because in initial mount there are no previous props to compare with.